# Concat several columns in a single one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have several files in excel with multiple columns and I want to concat each colmun in a single one.
Is there a performative code to do it?

```
df = pd.read_excel('exemple.xlsx', header=0, na_values='NA')
df.head()

joincolumn = pd.concat((df['dia1'] + df['dia1a'] + df['dia1b'] + df['dia1c'] + df['dia1d'] + df['A2'] + df['A2A'] + df['B2'] + df['B2B'] + df['C2'] + df['C2C'] +df['A3'] + df['A3A'] + df['B3'] + df['B3B'] + df['C3'] + df['C3C']))
```

[image]

this should look like:

0.423
0.469
0.428
0.495
0.448
0.51
0.494
0.425
0.489
0.465

it's not working!

Comment: Hi Marcos, are you trying to sum the columns or you really want to concatenate them as strings? It is not clear by your question was is the input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can achieved using [ravel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ravel.html)

Since no real data provided, for the sack of clear presentation, assume `dial` and `dia1a` as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dia1':[1, 2, 3, 4],'dia1a':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
```

Then  ravel these two column  gives:

```
print(pd.Series(df.values.ravel('F')))

1    2
2    3
3    4
4    A
5    B
6    C
7    D
```

If you would like to maintain the hierarchy, you can use [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dia1':[1, 2, 3, 4],'dia1a':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})

print(df.stack().reset_index())
```

which will output

```
   level_0 level_1  0
0        0    dia1  1
1        0   dia1a  A
2        1    dia1  2
3        1   dia1a  B
4        2    dia1  3
5        2   dia1a  C
6        3    dia1  4
7        3   dia1a  D
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much! it´s working now!

Comment: That great @MARCOSSANTOS, since the proposed method is working, maybe you can kindly  mark an [answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.